# Error when extracting lzma tar ball in terminal tar : "Unexpected EOF in archive"

Tags: tar, compression, extract

```
xz: (stdin): Unexpected end of input
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What does this mean?

What I entered:

```
sudo tar --lzma -xvf filename.tar.lzma
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An EOF (end of file) error means that the application was expecting there to be more data available, but it ran out of data and reached the end of the file.  In the case of trying to decompress a tarball, most likely the tarball is corrupt.  If you downloaded it from the internet, you could try downloading it again.

Comment: It's my /home directory :'(

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (use sudo if needed):

```
unlzma filename.tar.lzma
```

then:

```
tar xvf filename.tar
```

To get more info about the file:

```
lzmainfo filename.tar.lzma
```

[open-extract-lzma-under-rhel-centos-debian-ubuntu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/open-extract-lzma-under-rhel-centos-debian-ubuntu/)